# Getting millionth user like data

Tags: facebook, graph, facebook-fql

I am trying to see if I am able to receive the user like data from facebook to determine if can find the user who likes a page as the millionth (or 5thousands, etc.) user.

Is this possible? Has anyone done that? And if so, how did you go about it?

Thanks for you help, while I am getting slightly disappointed by the facebook docs....

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible with the API.

A possible solution would be to use the API to check the number of likes and notify you when you get close to the target.  Or, keep a close eye on the "New Likes" section of your page Admin Panel when you are getting close.  eg. when it reaches 1001 users, person 2nd from the top on your "New Likes" section is your 1000th user.

Comment: see the answer i linked - the users aren't displauyed in order of joining

Comment: They are in the "New Likes" section of the admin panel. This was introduced with Timeline for pages.  eg. New Likes: John Smith 6 minutes ago

Comment: True, those have been added, but it seems that currently is only possible via FQL and an app. Problem is that you can't force a user to visit an app and trigger the action automatically. As of this time you can get the Likes and the usernames(kid, etc.) but not in conjunction with a counter since those variables are either not stored with a relationship or (and this is my opinion) facebook does not give developers access to that yet. So we have to wait and see. But this is possible of you doing it only via an app or external page that requires user validation.